# Meal.hx:1: characters 0-7 is missing ;

Tags: haxe

Hello im trying to compile my simple code of haxe , and it still an error with Meal.hx:1: characters 0-7 is missing ;

i dont know where the error is,
here's the code:

Meal.hx

```
package MyFridge;
class Meal
{
public var name : String;
public function new(f_name : String)
{
this.name = f_name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look after the `package myFridge`
and uppercase from the code it will take effect for the compiler. good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

The class syntax looks valid.

So, Just some double checks;

- is this the exact code?
- is the file named Meal.hx?
- is it located in a folder (package) called MyFridge? Btw, not sur if this makes a difference, but it is common to use lowercase packages/foldernames.
- is this the only error?
- if this is part of a larger project, try create a separated test, to make sure the error is really related to this file.

Comment: The question was asked on the mailing list, the issue was the "MyFridge" package, packages must be lower case.  The error message was a bit cryptic, Simn is looking into fixing it :)

Answer (score 1):

The package name can only contain lowercase letters.

Like this:

```
package myfridge;
```

Give that a try.